# How to cut datetime rows by midnight?

Tags: r, datetime

my df looks like this:

```
event           start.time      end.time
connected       04.08.21 20:48  04.08.21 20:59
disconnected    04.08.21 20:59  06.08.21 14:29
```

How can I split the rows by midnight like so? Please note that the numbers of days skipped may vary: In my example it's 4-6 August but it could also be 10-17 September. A tidyverse solution would be highly appreciated!

```
event           start.time      end.time
connected       04.08.21 20:48  04.08.21 20:59
disconnected    04.08.21 20:59  04.08.21 23:59
disconnected    05.08.21 00:00  05.08.21 23:59
disconnected    06.08.21 00:00  06.08.21 14:29
```

Here is my reproducible code:

```
data <- data.frame(
  event = c("connected", "disconnected"),
  start.time = c("04.08.21 20:48", "04.08.21 20:59"),
  end.time = c("04.08.21 20:59", "06.08.21 14:29")
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jay.sf's answer, I could copy the logic to create the favored tidyverse solution:

```
data <- data.frame(
  event = c("connected", "disconnected"),
  start.time = c("04.08.21 20:48", "04.08.21 20:59"),
  end.time = c("04.08.21 20:59", "06.08.21 14:29")
)
data[-1] <- lapply(data[-1], function(x) as.POSIXct(strptime(x, format='%d.%m.%y %H:%M')))

data %>%
  # Group data by event
  group_by(event) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  # Create rows when times are "overnight"
  mutate(timestamp_seq = list(seq(from = start.time, to = end.time, by = "secs"))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(timestamp_seq = map(timestamp_seq, ~ .x[!duplicated(as.Date(.x)) | (as.POSIXct(.x) == max(.x))])) %>%
  unnest(timestamp_seq) %>%
  filter(!start.time==timestamp_seq) %>%
  # Correct the times
  mutate(start.time = if_else(row_number() == 1, start.time, lag(timestamp_seq)),
         tmp = if_else(lead(hms(format(start.time, format = "%H:%M:%S"))) == hms("00:00:00"), timestamp_seq, end.time),
         end.time = if_else(!is.na(tmp), tmp, end.time)) %>%
  select(-c(timestamp_seq, tmp))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `by`, you could make a `seq.POSIXt` for each `"min"`. In the sequences look where either midnight or midnight -1 isn't duplicated. Replace last 23:59 value with last observed timestamp.

```
data[-1] <- lapply(data[-1], strptime, format='%d.%m.%y %H:%M')  ## format time first

by(data, data$event, \(x) {
  sq <- seq.POSIXt(x[[2]], x[[3]], 'min')
  r <- data.frame(sq[!duplicated(strptime(sq, '%F'))], 
                  c(sq[!duplicated(strptime(sq, '%F 23:59'))][-1],  as.POSIXct(x[[3]]))) |> 
    setNames(names(x)[-1])
}) |> c(make.row.names=F) |> do.call(what='rbind')
#            start.time            end.time
# 1 2021-08-04 20:48:00 2021-08-04 20:59:00
# 2 2021-08-04 20:59:00 2021-08-04 23:59:00
# 3 2021-08-05 00:00:00 2021-08-05 23:59:00
# 4 2021-08-06 00:00:00 2021-08-06 14:29:00
```

**Old R versions:**

```
do.call(c(by(data, data$event, function(x) {
    sq <- seq.POSIXt(x[[2]], x[[3]], "min")
    r <- setNames(data.frame(sq[!duplicated(strptime(sq, "%F"))], 
        c(sq[!duplicated(strptime(sq, "%F 23:59"))][-1], as.POSIXct(x[[3]]))), 
        names(x)[-1])
}), make.row.names = F), what = "rbind")
```

---

*Data:*

```
data <- structure(list(event = c("connected", "disconnected"), start.time = c("04.08.21 20:48", 
"04.08.21 20:59"), end.time = c("04.08.21 20:59", "06.08.21 14:29"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! May I ask you to offer a solution that work for tibbles as well? Your code only works for structures for me. Also, where is formatting (e.g., \(x) or "|>") coming from?

Comment: @diggi2395 Sounds to me like you're using a pretty outdated R version. Added alternative code. Better keep your R up to date.